# Showing $(n)^{\overline{k}}=(n+k-1)^{\underline{k}}=(-1)^k\cdot(-n)^{\underline{k}}$, for rising and falling factorials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

I have to prove equality with falling factorials
$$(n)^{\underline{k}} = n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) $$  and rising factorials $$(n)^{\overline{k}}=n(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1)$$

> Show:
> $$(n)^{\overline{k}}=(n+k-1)^{\underline{k}}= (-1)^k  \cdot(-n)^{\underline{k}}$$

Can anyone please give me a hint? I tried so many ways but it got nowhere...my tries:

$$(n+k-1)^{\underline{k}}=(n+k-1)(n+k-2)...(n+k)$$
$$(-n)^{\underline{k}}=-n(-n-1)...(-n-k+1)$$

Comment: What you're trying to show doesn't make sense, since you define the rising factorial to be $n(n+1)\dots(n+k-1)$, but are trying to show it equals $(n+k-1)$.

Comment: Can you prove when $k=1$?  When $k=2$?

Comment: @KellyBrower The term in the middle must have the exponent left out.

Comment: @KellyBrower im sorry i forgot something. now it has to be correct

Comment: Did you try to write down $(n+k-1)^\underline{k}$ according to the definition? The same with $(-n)^\underline{k}$?

Comment: now its right...

Comment: @user yesss like i definite

Comment: @user yes i tried

Comment: So please include the result of the try in your question. By the way it will also answer the question.

Comment: @user ok i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also convenient to use the product symbol to explicitly see the lower and upper limit. We have
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{n^{\overline{k}}}&=n(n+1)\cdots(n+(k-1)
\color{blue}{=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+j)}\tag{1}\\
\color{blue}{n^{\underline{k}}}&=n(n-1)\cdots(n-(k-1))
\color{blue}{=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{n^{\overline{k}}}
> &=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+j)\tag{3}\\
> &=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+(k-1-j))\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(n+k-1)^{\underline{k}}}\tag{5}\\
> \\
> \color{blue}{n^{\overline{k}}}
> &=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+j)\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^k\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(-n-j)\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-n)^{\underline{k}}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use the product representation (1).
- In (4) we change the order of multiplication by replacing the index $j$ with $k-1-j$.
  \begin{align*}
  \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+j)&=(n+0)(n+1)\cdots (n+k-2)(n+k-1)\\
  &=(n+(k-1))(n+(k-2))\cdots(n+1)(n+0)\\
  &=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+(k-1-j))
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we use (2) with $n$ substituted by $n+k-1$.
- In (6) we factor out $(-1)$ $k$ times.
- In (7) we use (2) with $n$ substituted by $-n$.

Comment: thank you for that advice :)

Comment: can u please write down the step with changing order ? i dont know how to do that with product symbol

Comment: @kurlya: I've added some more details.

Comment: ok thank you very much now its clear to me :)

Comment: @kurlya: Great! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Comment: yes very useful! :) do you have an idea for my next question upload? its again with falling and rising factorials. and i dont have to do a combinatoric proof like someone showed me in an other question. i think i have to do it inductive

Comment: oh thank you. there is now an answer, maybe you can check if its a full proof

Comment: @kurlya: The proof is well done.

Answer (score 1):

Hints.

In the first line you made an error. It should be (please check!):
$$(n+k-1)^{\underline{k}}=(n+k-1)(n+k-2)\cdots\color{red}n$$
Now recall that multiplication is commutative and revert the factors!

In the second line everything is correct. Now multiply every factor by $-1$. To keep the correct sign of the whole expression multiply it by another $-1$ for each factor.

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: ok i have it now. But one question: if k is even then you have +1 and then multiplying by -1 would not be correct?

Comment: Why would it be not correct? Do you understand how "multiply it by another $−1$ **for each factor**" work? Did you count the number of the factors?

Comment: does an even or unven k change the sign of the product?

Comment: @kurlya If $n$ is negative then $n^\underline{k}$ is negative for odd $k$ and positive for even $k$.

Comment: i still dont understand. can you explain more detailed.

Comment: $(-4)^\underline{2}=(-4)(-5)=+20, (-4)^\underline{3}=(-4)(-5)(-6)=-120.$